# Large TableView with thumbnails crashing app in Titanium

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have a table view with custom rows (77 to be exact). Each custom row has a thumbnail and a title.

The thumbnail is loaded from a sprite via:

```
var row = Alloy.createWidget('com.dop.vforummobile.sliderow');

//-- thumbBlob is a jpg file that is 107x6160, maybe the large sprite is the problem?

var cropped = thumbBlob.imageAsCropped({
  height:80,
  width:107,
  x:0,
  y:i * 80
});
row.init(slides[i], i, cropped);
```

row.init(args) is below

```
var init = function(data, index, cropped)
{
  $.title.text = (index + 1) + '. '  + data.title;
  $.slideRow.startTime = data.startTime;
  $.slideRow.searchFilter = data.title + ' ' + data.slideText;
  if (Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') $.slideRow.title = $.slideRow.searchFilter;
  if (Ti.Platform.osname != 'android') $.slideRow.selectionStyle = Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE;
  $.thumb.image = cropped;
};
```

I noticed if I don't set the thumbnail, the performance on the tableview is much greater and it doesn't crash so I know it has to do with the thumbnails.

The tableview loads fine, its when I start scrolling rapidly, the tableview begins to lag on my iPad and then it crashes.

I noticed if I scroll slow enough to get to the bottom of the tableview without it crashing and then scroll rapidly, its fine. It's like they all loaded into memory so I can scroll at any rate.

Any ideas on this? To me it seems the rows don't load until they are actually visible and if I scroll to fast, too many rows are being loaded and I run out of memory and it crashes

Comment: try using `className` property on tableViewRow, it makes the row reusable.

Comment: @Swanand can you expand on this?

Comment: @ Ronnie when you simply create the tableViewRow, all rows remains in the memory as long as the tableView is visible. By using `className` property the row becomes reusable. When you use className titanium rows are created by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in native. The good thing about that is when row disappears from the screen its memory is used by another appearing cell, and hence manages memory by itself.

Comment: @ Ronnie  And also check something with the `imageAsCropped` method, because sometimes it takes time to generate `blob`, so check for that also. If your `cropped` is not null, then only pass it to the init method. Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set the image as blob and do so every time the table is rendered. I would suggest to cut the sprite only the first time, save them to device and then pass the paths when you render the table.

To overall greatly improve list performance, switch from `TableView` to the newer `ListView`.

A few notes to improve your code:

- Use `OS_ANDROID` instead of `Ti.Platform.osname != 'android'`
- Use `#slideRow[platform=ios] { selectionStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE }` in your `widget.tss` instead of styling inline in `widget.js`

Comment: I set the image as a blob only once and pass the cropped image `var cropped = thumbBlob.imageAsCropped()`, which returns an image, to the custom row. I appreciate the suggestions on improving my code and will implement those. Also, switching from table view to list view...hopefully its pretty seamless

Comment: So I am reading up on `ListView` and it appears you cannot directly manipulate a `ListItem` once the list is created. You have to generate a new list. A problem I see is that each of my custom rows contain a hidden "check" image. Once the row has been viewed, I set the visibility of the green check to true. It sounds like I'd have to rebuild the list every time I need to do that. Am I not understanding that correctly?

Comment: On another note, I took the sprite and broke them up into individual thumbnails totalling 77 small jpegs (about 4kb each). I put them jpgs into my custom row widgets images folder and placed them from there just to see if it has something to do with the blob. Loading them from there was much smoother and it isn't crashing. I will try your idea of breaking up the sprite and saving the images to the device and loading them that way. Thanks again, I'll report back

Comment: I just noticed I was wrong in my first comment. `imageAsCropped` returns a new blob, not an image. I always thought it returned an image. In that case, I'll see if I can convert that to an image before setting the thumbnail on my custom row

Comment: With ListView you can also manipulate an item after rendering. You can find an example at http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/ListViews-section-37521650_ListViews-ListViewitemclickEvent

Indeed the performance should increase if you work with file paths instead of blobs. Let me know if you have any further problems with this.

Comment: I ended up cropping the sprite, saving the cropped image to the devices `tempDirectory` via `getTempDirectory()` and then passing that path to the row. I noticed on iOS it worked fine going between different sprites (I would crop different sprites with the same names like slide1, slide2, slide3 etc) but on android they wouldn't be overwritten so I started placing them in timestamped folders. Here is my paired down solution http://pastie.org/10002740